# mysql - data collection multiple table?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table 'sales'
id refid invoice itemid price
1  001   1501    ss01   12000

table 'purchase'
id itemid price
1  ss01   10200

table 'reference'
id refid refname
1  001   bedul
```

I have this three table in my sql DB, so how to make them turn into single table like below using mysql query :

```
table 

id refid refname invoice itemid sellprice buyprice profit
1  001   bedul   1501    ss01   12000     10200    1800
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result table is not detail enough but you can try this :

```
select sales.id, sales.refid, reference.refname, sales.invoice,
sales.itemid, sales.price as sellprice, purchase.price as buyprice,
sales.price - purchase.price as profit
from sales
left outer join reference on reference.refid = sales.refid
left outer join purchase on purchase.itemid = sales.itemid
```

Comment: how if i am trying to make same result base on `refname` search result ?

Answer (score 0):

The following has been tested and confirmed as effective...

```
SELECT sales.id,
       sales.refid,
       reference.refname,
       sales.invoice,
       sales.itemid,
       sales.price AS sellprice,
       purchase.price AS buyprice,
       sales.price - purchase.price AS profit
FROM sales, purchase, reference
WHERE sales.refid = reference.refid AND
      sales.itemid = purchase.itemid;
```