# CI Advanced SQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Thank for helping me on this question :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182460/mysql-data-collection-multiple-table
```

And now as I am was novice on framework. Can anyone help me to transform this query into something understand by CodeIgniter 3 and running correctly :

```
select sales.id, sales.refid, reference.refname, sales.invoice,
sales.itemid, sales.price as sellprice, purchase.price as buyprice,
sales.price - purchase.price as profit from sales
left outer join reference on reference.refid = sales.refid
left outer join purchase on purchase.itemid = sales.itemid
```

And for addtional question where to place or how to make CI perform multiple query, like this :

```
INSERT INTO sales VALUES ( null , 001 , 1501 , ss01 , 12000 );
INSERT INTO purchase VALUES ( null , ss01 , 10200 );
UPDATE reference SET purchasedate = now() WHERE refid = 'ss01';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think no need to convert query to codeigniter.

Just use `query()`. in CI.

```
$query = "select sales.id, sales.refid, reference.refname, sales.invoice,
sales.itemid, sales.price as sellprice, purchase.price as buyprice,
sales.price - purchase.price as profit from sales
left outer join reference on reference.refid = sales.refid
left outer join purchase on purchase.itemid = sales.itemid";

$this->db->query($query
```

If at all you want to convert the query to codeigniter, it should be like this,

```
$this->db->select("select sales.id, sales.refid, reference.refname, sales.invoice,sales.itemid, sales.price as sellprice, purchase.price as buyprice,sales.price - purchase.price as profit");
$this->db->join("reference", "reference.refid = sales.refid", "left outer");
$this->db->join("purchase", "purchase.itemid = sales.itemid", "left outer");
$this->db->get("sales");
```

**SECOND PART**

Use transactions for this,

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

See here for more [refernce](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html)

Or use `mysql_multi_query()`,

See this for [`mysql_multi_query()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp)

Comment: And how about second question ? About Multiple Query ?